# Error displaying data from DB to predefined columns of datagrid View on button click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the following code:

```
string getinputs = "SELECT ir.plu_code PLU_Code,ir.barcode Barcode,ir.product_name Product_Name  FROM inventory_register ir,inventory_value iv WHERE ir.dept_id='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND ir.barcode = iv.barcode";
connection.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(getinputs, connection);
MySqlCommandBuilder cmdbuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);
BindingSource bindsrc = new BindingSource();
DataGridView datagridv = new DataGridView();
bindsrc.DataSource = dt;
datagridv.DataSource = bindsrc;
connection.Close();
```

I have three predefined columns in `datagridview1` say '`PLU_Code`', '`Barcode`' and '`Product_Name`'.

I want to display the result (more than one row) of the select query in the datagridview. But I am not getting any.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Off topic, but: your code is vulnerable for SQL injection.

Comment: Problem is when i click on the button there is no rows displayed in datagridview

Comment: are you sure you are getting some data when you do adpter.Fille(dt)?

Comment: @Stefan You mean the flow is wrong>/

Comment: there are no data displayed @Fabricio

Comment: @Ameena: no, check this answer for details: inserting your textbox data directly in your SQL statement is vulnerable for hackers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: yea, I know that is not data displayed. What I meant to ask was if you know if the result DataTable has some rows in it. If you are getting data from your query.

Comment: yes the result of the query is two rows. but i dont think i am getting data in adapter.fill(dt). am i missing something in the code?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result. I achieved two empty rows on using @user4340666 code. when i scrolled the grid i found the set of data's been added as new columns leaving predefined column cells empty. so i just cleared the columns.

```
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            string getinputs = "SELECT ir.plu_code PLU_Code,ir.barcode Barcode,ir.product_name Product_Name  FROM inventory_register ir,inventory_value iv WHERE ir.dept_id='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND ir.barcode = iv.barcode";
            connection.Open();

            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(getinputs, connection);
            MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);

            datagridview1.DataSource = table;

            connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
                string getinputs = "SELECT ir.plu_code PLU_Code,ir.barcode Barcode,ir.product_name Product_Name  FROM inventory_register ir,inventory_value iv WHERE ir.dept_id='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND ir.barcode = iv.barcode";
                connection.Open();

                MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(getinputs, connection);
                MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(table);

                datagridview1.DataSource = table;

                connection.Close();
```

Comment: Hi. result of the select query is two rows. After trying ur code, i am getting two empty rows in datagridview(no data in cells)

Comment: Ok try to use parameters in SQL statements

Comment: u mean to say "cmd.parameters.add"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
string getinputs = "Select Query";
connection.Open();

MySqlCommandBuilder cmdbuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(getinputs,connection);
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdbuilder);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);

DataGridView datagridv = new DataGridView();
datagridv.DataSource = dt;

datagridv.DataBind();

connection.Close();
```